# Several balls in a limited square and don't collide with each other

Tags: iphone, box2d

With box2d,I want to put some balls in a limited square.They will not collide with other balls but will come back when hit the edge.What properties should I give to the balls and square?

If I set the edge is b2_dynamicbody and ball is b2_kinematicbody,balls don't collide but they just go there way and no reaction with the edge(the edge moved away with the balls -_-").To the contrary,balls will collide each other.I hope there is some way to ignore balls' collide but react with the edge.

Comment: take a look at b2Filter property of b2Fixture. There is a detailed explanation of it in box2d manual

Answer (score 0):

That's the answer which Andrew answered in comment above.I copied it and let others who meets the same problem see it's solved.Best thanks to Andrew(http://stackoverflow.com/users/444088/andrew)

'take a look at b2Filter property of b2Fixture. There is a detailed explanation of it in box2d manual.'

Additional,here is the link to box2d official manual
http://www.box2d.org/manual.html